# Conditional $match Monogdb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I hope someone has answer for my question.

I am trying for search query

1. my match will be varies
2. sometime user can forget to submit input text

however on click with input text or not, 
it must return results (without input text will return all array like as without match stage and with input text will return match arrays).

1. if there is input text

> {$match: {$text:  { $search: "bla" } }

2. if there is no input text

> {$match: "" }

empty input text returns "error: the match filter must be an expression in an object"

I mean like as the following way,

```
var myMatch = {}
if( input=="bla")
{ myMatch = "{$text:  { $search: "bla" }"  }"
 else if(input=="")
{ myMatch = "" }

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": myMatch} ])
```

which returns "error: the match filter must be an expression in an object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`else if(input=="")
{ myMatch = {} }`

As the error says $match requires an object.

Answer (score 0):

Build your query conditional, the match should only be there if the user has added any text in the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can write more generic code. Let's start with your code and see what we can change

```
function logic {
   var aggregationPipeLine= []
   if(input=="bla")
      aggregationPipeLine = [{ "$match" : {$text:  { $search: "bla" }  }}];

   performAggregataion(aggregationPipeLine, function(err, res)=> { 
     // Your code 
   });
}
function performAggregataion (pipeline, callback) {
     db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).exec(callback);
}
```

So in this way you defined you aggreation pipeline when you want to do more operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMatch = {}

if(input == "bla"){
  myMatch["$text"]={};
  myMatch["$text"]["$search"]="bla";
}

db.collection.aggregate([
{ "$match": myMatch} ])
```

$match require {} Object if your condition is true make you pipeline $match object other wise {} object pass not any error